# How to upload Image to server and get back at time in GWT.?

Tags: java, gwt

I have uploaded images to server directory in jboss.
Path is standalone/data/..
Now,How to get images from server in GWT.??

Comment: I did this and it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491025/how-to-get-image-with-servlet-and-display-it-using-gwt-image-class

Answer (score 0):

You may simply create a `new Image()` and [pass the path to the image](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#Image%28java.lang.String%29) (if it is accessable by a browser). If it is ot accessable, you will need to create a [simple Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2007/04/imageservlet.html), that reads the file fomr the disk, and writes it out to the browser.

Comment: I have tried to create a servlet and read images from that but i can't.

Comment: I've added a link to a Servlet, that will deliver a File from the Filesystem. You will have to change some parts of hte Servlet, but I think this will be helpful.

Comment: What's the issue concerning to the Servlet you have created? it is properly declared in web.xml and mapped into it? Can you access it by e.g. a web browser? are there any exception that your browser would be throwing?

Answer (score 0):

There are **multiple ways** but i find out this **2 ways** to **upload the image file** and get back.

**1)** upload it on destination location using `fileItem.write(tempFile);`
and get back using

```
File file = new File(filename);
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

handle that response at client side..

**2)** Upload is same using  `FileItem.write`
If it is in war or project folder then you can access it directly by specifying URL which you access that site.

like, if you war/project folder is "ImageUpload.war"
and access link is :- **"http://samirsavasani.com:8888/"**
You have uploaded file in it like "ImageUpload.war"-"Images"-YOUR UPLOADED IMAGES
then you can access it just like.. :- **"http://samirsavasani.com:8888/Images/YOUR IMAGE NAME"**